# Does using ActiveStorage variants increases performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-activestorage, variant

I have a site where I load images of products. My images are originally bigger, and I resize their display by css. I'm looking for some performance upgrade and thought about variants, but then I found in documentation `Note that to create a variant it's necessary to download the entire blob file from the service and load it into memory.` 
So the question is: does resizing images by using variants increases website performance, and is it cachable the same way as original image?